# How can I determine trending stories from a collection of news data

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a portal that fetches news from hundreds of resources around the web. How can I be able to use these data to determine trending stories ?

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Asked previously here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674064/identifying-trending-stories-in-sql-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674064/identifying-trending-stories-in-sql-server)

Comment: No one suggested anything there.

Comment: Then you should update the original question with better or more specific information. Don't simply repeat yourself here. "The definition of insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results." ~Albert Einstein  :-)

Comment: At least if you wanna give an advice wich I respect it at least try to help here by providing a suggestion.

Comment: My advice is that the scope of your current question is far too ambitious and broad to be answered in this platform. Narrow your focus. Identify a specific problem. Show us what you've tried to do so far. Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a good dictionary with all kinds of words and their forms.
2. Split the words in a news story and collect statistics on those words.
3. Group stories by their word statistics signature and closeness in date-time space.

Comment: Is this the technique twitter, or any other news site uses ? Does Sql Server 2008 Data mining can help me in this ? Thanks.

Comment: @Joseph Ghassan If you know SSAS then go for it, it's much more powerful than any feeble attempts to solve this problem in plain tsql.

Comment: Do you know active community about SSAS, or some online tutorials? thanks.